# apply a function to a subset of a data frame

Tags: r

Saw some relevant questions but nothing that really gave me what I needed (or perhaps I just didn't understand it).

I have a data fram that looks like the following:

```
Date   City A   City B City C
8/17     55       65    75
8/18     48       85    23
```

except that it is way more than 3 cities. I want to apply a function to every column in the data frame except for date -- I could apply the function to each column and that would do the trick, but I'm looking for some kind of notation that will apply the function to everything except for the date column (to accomodate DF's with differing column names).

Was trying apply, transform, but no luck. should be mentioned that I've been workin with R for approximately a month now so I am not very good at it (yet!).

Appreciate any help you all can offer, thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to `melt` your data first into long format.  `library(reshape2) melt(df, id.vars='Date')`

Comment: `sapply(df[,-1], function(i) ...)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to apply on `df[,-1]` :

```
df=data.frame(Date=c("A","B"), City_A=c(55,48),City_B=c(65,85),City_C=c(75,23))
apply(df[,-1],1,sum)
[1] 195 156
```

And if you don't know the index of your column but just the name, you can use :
`-(which(colnames(df)=="Date"))` instead of `-1`:

```
apply(df[,-(which(colnames(df)=="Date"))],1,sum)
[1] 195 156
```

If you prefer the lapply version, you can use

```
lapply(df[,-(which(colnames(df)=="Date"))],sum)
```

That will return a list

Comment: If they're dealing with a `data.frame` it'll be safer to use `lapply` instead of `apply`

Comment: I add it to the answer